# JavaFX fill 1 column with data of HashMap

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to fill a TableView with data of a HashMap(just the value not the key).
But somehow I don't really understand how to do it in JavaFX easily..

This is my table definition from the fxml.

```
<TableView fx:id="activeuserTable" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="8.0" prefHeight="325.0" prefWidth="234.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="169.0" text="C1" />
    </columns>
    <columnResizePolicy>
        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
    </columnResizePolicy>
</TableView>
```

In java:

```
...
@FXML private TableView activeuserTable;
...
...
Iterator it = users.entrySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {

    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
    activeuserTable.getColumns().add(pairs.getValue()); // but yeah not really working 
    it.remove(); 
}
```

But yeah somehow it don't work :S I'm missing something which I can't see.. I'm working not so long with JavaFX and read much about filling a table but it was somehow complicated and I didn't really understand it.

Hope you can help me!
Greetz

Comment: Please go through [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CEGHGDFA) and let us know, if you still face issue.

Comment: I went through the documentation 1to1 and really slowly ported it for my needs and got it working :)